# How to get height of rendered HTML document in C#

Tags: c#, html, browser, rendering

So the question is how can I get height of rendered HTML document, which will not have vertical scrollbar? Thanks!

Comment: How are rendering that HTML document?

Comment: I am not sure it's really possible to do with C# since it's server side.  Every browser is different, the height is going to be different on a small screen than large screen.  Really javascript is your best option.

Comment: I don't know. That's why I answered this question :) I think System.Web.Browser class.

Comment: @Caimen There's ability to pass some client browser parameters to calculate height of document.

Comment: I want to mean, how are **you** rendering that HTML document? If you are using the WebBrowser control, your rendering engine is Trident / IE ...

Comment: Yes, I think rendering by IE engine is quite enough.

Comment: @kseen you could do this but the server side will have already went through it's process by the time the dom can figure this out.  The only way I can think tell the server side what the height is, would be by an ajax call and I'm not sure how useful that will be in the your case.  If your page is based off ajax calls, then there I could see a way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using HTML + JavaScript.

Try using that [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9FFUe/1/)
Add more `<p>` and re-run to see that the height changes.

Html:

```
<body id="inner-body-el">
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p id="height-display"></p>
</body>
```

Javascript (w/ jQuery)

```
$(function(){
    var w = $('#inner-body-el').height();
    $('#height-display').html(w);
});
```

Comment: This is the best solution, if you want to pass the height to C#, you will need an ajax call.  C# itself cannot truly figure out the height of the document until it has loaded in the dom like with this function shown here.